# Why was my question closed? It adhered to the FAQ

Tags: support, specific-question, closed-questions

I know there are plenty of these type of questions, and I apologise in advance, but I'm curious why my question was closed:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8139994/moving-hiding-the-wp-admin-page

This was a legitimate question that concerned how to program something in a website's .htaccess / zeus equivalent.

It's been open for more than 6 months, with an appropriate answer.

It's been closed as 'off topic' but I'm just wondering how it's off topic. Sorry if I seem like I'm complaining, but I'm interested to know why it's considered off topic so I may avoid making the same mistake in future.

Comment: From the answers it looks more like a sysadmin question than a programming one.

Comment: Looks like it's *really* specific to Wordpress.  And it doesn't completely involve programming (i.e. "Is there a way to hide the wp-admin page, **perhaps through a plugin**?).

Answer (score 11):

Since the question doesn't really involve programming, you should try asking your question [on the wordpress site](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/). Or just search there for similar questions, e.g. [this one](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/106/can-i-rename-the-wp-admin-folder).

Comment: Thanks, this helps. I asked it here just in-case there was a programming method, not just a WordPress method. I'll keep them appropriate!